# Scrolling text on video

Tags: post-production, subtitles

I want to take an mp3 podcast and its transcript and create a video of the text scrolling vertically on the screen with the audio.

I need to scroll 10~20 lines of text so that I don't have to sync each line.

I used MS MovieMaker for this job but now I want to automate the process.

What tool do you recommend, ffmpeg, AviSynth? Also startup tips and examples would be very helpful as I don't have any experience in video processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x400 -i "input.mp3" ^
-vf [in]drawtext=fontfile=%fontFile%:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=h-t*(th/%T%)-h/2:textfile='input.txt',^
drawtext=fontfile=c\\:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=19:fontcolor=red:x=0:y=h-lh:text=%%{pts^\:hms} ^
-c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast -t 21 -r 30 -hide_banner -codec:a copy output.mp4 && start output.mp4
```

Note that "^" symbol is for breaking a long line in batch file.

This takes input.mp3 audio and raw text from input.txt and generates a video file with titles scrolling from bottom up.

Unfortunately, I can't provide any explanation for the ffmpeg switches as I simply Googled for it a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I hope after 3 years you managed to solve it. But here is an option anyway.

Use any decent video editor.

Some editors have "text" effects, like an "end credits scene". On Davinci Resolve (which is free) you simply add this effect and control the speed, font, color.

Some other programs simply allow you to import an image file with a transparent background and move it around the frame.

You can prepare this PNG file in Gimp, add the text there and import and move it on the editing program.

Some programs that allow you to move elements (Keyframing) are Hit film express and OpenShot, besides Davinci Resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but I was looking for solution to automate this process because I have quite a lot of file to process.